# One, two, three or more extreme values on the unit circle for x(1-y)?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, parametrization

How many extreme values can you find for $x(1-y)$ for $(x,y)$ on the unit cirle $x^2+y^2=1$?

When using parametrization I find three but with Lagrange multiplier only two. What would be correct? And what would the values be?

For **parametrization** I used:

$x=\cos(t)$

$y=\sin(t)$

Leading to $2\sin^2(t)-\sin(t)-1=0$ for which I used substitution $u=\sin(t)$ $\Rightarrow$ $2u^2-u-1=0$ giving $u=1$ and $u=-\frac{1}{2}$. Not sure how to proceed?

For **Lagrange** we find $y=1$ and $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ which inserted in $y^2 = y+x^2$ gives $x=+-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$. Inserted in $x(1-y)$ gives the two values:

$f_1=\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}$

$f_2=-\frac{3\sqrt3}{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set up the pullback $\hat f(t):=x(t)\bigl(1-y(t)\bigr)=\cos t(1-\sin t)$ and now have to determine the $t$-values for which $f'(t)=0$. The latter happens iff $\sin t=u\in\bigl\{1,-{1\over2}\bigr\}$. We therefore have to find out for which values of $t$ modulo $2\pi$ we have $\sin t=1$ or $\sin t=-{1\over2}$. As is well known these values are 
$$t\in\left\{{\pi\over2},{7\pi\over6},{11\pi\over6}\right\}\qquad({\rm mod}\ 2\pi)$$
(note that $\sin{\pi\over6}=\sin 30^\circ={1\over2}$).
We therefore have the three conditionally critical points ${\bf z}_i=(\cos t_i,\sin t_i)\in S^1$ given by 
$${\bf z}_1=(0,1),\quad{\bf z}_2=\left(-{\sqrt{3}\over2},-{1\over2}\right),\quad{\bf z}_3=\left({\sqrt{3}\over2},-{1\over2}\right)\ .$$
We then can say that
$$\max\bigl\{f(x,y)\,\bigm|\,(x,y)\in S^1\bigr\}=\max_{1\leq i\leq3} f({\bf z}_i)\ ,$$
and simlarly for the $\min$. You now have to compute and compare these values.

Comment: How do I find $$t\in\left\{{\pi\over2},{7\pi\over6},{11\pi\over6}\right\}\qquad({\rm mod}\ 2\pi)\ .$$ for $\sin t=u\in\bigl\{1,-{1\over2}\bigr\}$?

Answer (score 1):

What parameterisation did you use? $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$?

For the latter, there are three values of $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$ for for which $\frac{d}{dt} x(1-y)=0$, however one of those is not an extremum, being a point of inflection instead.

Comment: Yes, I used that one. I get u=1 and u=-1/2 but then I have troubles finding the right radian.

Comment: I have now extended the first post.

Comment: $u=\sin t$, so if $\sin t = 1$, you get $t=\frac\pi2$. For $\sin t=-\frac12$, you get $t=-\frac\pi6$ or $t=-\frac{5\pi}6$.

Look up "solving exact values trig functions" or similar. You surely covered that topic some time in high school, though you may have forgotten it. 

Alternatively, you can use the values of $\sin t$ to find $y$ and therefore $x$, without any need to find $t$.